# How to calculate location of the shape in Excel 2007?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to export a few shapes into excel file. I using Excel 2007.

I would like to put a rectangle shape on given x and y points. I don't understand how the XSSFClientAnchor class works. How to calculate the start point of the X and Y coordinates? How to calculate end points of X and Y? In what measure are the first 4 parameters of the XSSFClientAnchor class?

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have got some replies here: http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/How-to-calculate-location-of-the-shape-in-Excel-2007-td5711113.html

Just posting to make life of other visitors easy finding details.